# AZURE FUNCTIONS: PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH? for pdf2image

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, poppler, poppler-utils

I am getting this error "Result: Failure Exception: PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH? for azure functions."

I am using pdf2image library's convert_from_path() to process my pdf to image. This works fine while I test from local. While publishing the function to azure, poppler-utils package also gets installed there but still the error comes. I saw a lot of threads related to this error and tried it but wanted to know , if anyone experienced this specifically for azure functions.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for this issue has been provided in the [thread](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image/issues/142)

*"you should try to troubleshoot it by simply having a function that opens a process and prints the help of pdftoppm (poppler). You will be able to get a different message that might be more relevant.
Something like this:*

```
  import subprocess

  def main():
   p = subprocess.Popen(["pdftoppm", "-h"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   out, err = p.communicate()
   print(out, err)
```

*As a general recommendation, I would bundle the poppler utilities with your package to avoid installing it in the function environment. You can call the function with poppler_path."*

Comment: Thanks Jaya. Yes I tried this. Still, I had the same issue. So I decided to deploy the functions via docker into azure container registry. This worked for me without any issues.